# How to validate properties in loopback remote method?

Tags: express, loopback

Recently I have started learning Loopback. I have tried to add required, min and max.

Here is my remote method in json file with parameters :

```
{
  "name": "registration",
  "methods": {
    "registrationIn": {
      "accepts": [
        {
          "arg": "firstname",
          "type": "string",
          "min": 1,
          "max": 25,       // same for here 
          "required": true,
          "description": "Firstname of the person.",
          "http": {
            "source": "form"
          }
        }
        {
          "arg": "mobile",
          "type": "number",
          "min": 1,   // since required it correct but not checking i removed required
          "max": 10, // not working 
          "required": true,  // working
          "description": "",
          "http": {
            "source": "form"
          }
        }
      ],
      "returns": [],
      "description": "This method used to registration.",
      "http": [{
        "path": "/registrationIn",
        "verb": "post"
      }]
    }
}
```

required property is working fine but min and max is not working. 
Can anyone guide me to where i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link [validation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Validating-model-data.html)

**You can add validation on model.**

```
    module.exports = function(user) {
      user.validatesLengthOf('password', {min: 5, message: {min: 'Password is too short'}});
 }
```

Comment: dude, may I not add min, max in json itself ?

Comment: Please check https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-methods.html its not provide such parameter in remote method.

Comment: Thanks @Dani. I checked it is not implemented yet in v3.x of loopback.